# A dataframe of n column given and I want to count frequency of a particular number from each column

Tags: python, pandas

'''
dataframe is like

1  2  4  ....n

0  2  0  ....n

1  0  4  ....n

0  0  4  ....n

now i want to **count 1 from column 1, count 2 from column 2,count 4 from column 3** and so on.

but i also want to count few values by adding columns like

1+2  ,        1+4     ,    2+4   ,   1+2+4

0+2  ,        0+0     ,    2+0   ,   0+2+0

1+0  ,         1+4    ,     0+4  ,    1+0+4

0+0  ,         0+4    ,     0+4  ,    0+0+4

Count 3      count 5   count 6     count 7  from above columns respectively.

**count 1 from column a, 2 from column b, 3 from column a+b, 4 from column c, 5 from column a+c, 6 from column b+c, 7 from column a+b+c. like this.**

Store all these values/number in list, array or dataframe like

Values/Number , Title , Frequency

1 , a , 2

2 , b , 2

3 , a+b , 1

4 , c , 3

5 , a+c , 2

6 , b+c , 1

7 , a+b+c , 1

'''

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Provide a reproducible dataframe (preferably the `pd.DataFrame` code for the dataframe) and the expected output according to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60227336/2901002) first:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031
comb = chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(df.columns, x), range(2, len(df.columns)+1)))

cols = df.columns
for c in comb:
    df[f'{"+".join(c)}'] = df.loc[:, c].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b  c  a+b  a+c  b+c  a+b+c
0  1  2  4    3    5    6      7
1  0  2  0    2    0    2      2
2  1  0  4    1    5    4      5
3  0  0  4    0    4    4      4

df1 = df.apply(pd.value_counts)
print (df1)
     a    b    c  a+b  a+c  b+c  a+b+c
0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN    NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
2  NaN  2.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0    1.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
4  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  1.0  2.0    1.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN    1.0
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0    NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1.0
```

And then [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) for new DataFrame, [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index and last `rename` columns:

```
c = {'index':'Values/Number','idxmax':'Title','max':'Frequency'}
df2 = df1.agg(['idxmax','max'], axis=1).reset_index().rename(columns=c)
print (df2)
   Values/Number  Title Frequency
0              0      a         2
1              1      a         2
2              2      b         2
3              3    a+b         1
4              4      c         3
5              5    a+c         2
6              6    b+c         1
7              7  a+b+c         1
```